# creating automation object (COM) takes lot of time

Tags: qtp, hp-uft, createobject

Using UFT 12.02, I recently encountered this peculiar issue which wasn't earlier.

Whenever I try to create an automation object, UFT takes exponentially lot of time to execute it.

```
Set WinReplay = CreateObject("Mercury.DeviceReplay")
Set mysendkeys = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
```

It takes about 70-80 Seconds to execute either of the code above. Its surprising as this issue wasn't encountered earlier and the scripts executed just fine until recently. What's more surprising is that no new software/Application were installed that could have this issue (if at all) and UFT starting behaving this out of the blue.

Did anyone of you faced same issues ? Am i missing or overlooking something here ?

Comment: Can you try debugging this code and see the value of `err.number` in the watch as soon as these lines are executed? Are you getting a non-zero error number?

Comment: Nope that didn't work as there isn't any error - UFT keeps on 'Running' while on this code for the mentioned time.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked was to reinstall UFT. However I'm certain that there could be another easier way to solve this though such issues happen intermittently.

So for now the simplest and the most obvious solution is to reinstall the UFT.